# How to make @each observer trigger just once

Tags: ember.js

I have an each observer which observes an array property. I have an action that goes through the array and sets that property, so it gets fired multiple times. I am wondering if I could make it trigger just once. For eg:

```
    App.EmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

      content:Ember.A([
        Ember.Object.create({'name':'a','active':true}),
        Ember.Object.create({'name':'b','active':false}),
        Ember.Object.create({'name':'c','active':false})
      ]),

      test: function(){
        console.log('inside here');//WANT THIS TO FIRE JUST ONCE
      }.observes('content.@each.active'),

      setActive: function(name){
        var self= this;
        Ember.run(function(){
           self.get('content').forEach(function (emp) {
               emp.set('active', (emp.get('name') === name));
            });  
        });

      }

    });
```

And here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vuyezahi/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're changing two values in the array.  So technically it should fire twice, but if you want you can throttle the method to only call once within a specified period (I did 10ms).

```
      test: function(){
        Em.run.throttle(this, this.test2, 10);
      }.observes('content.@each.active'),

      test2: function(){
        console.log('inside here');
      },
```

http://jsbin.com/vuyezahi/6/edit